# Show content on certain URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an online store solution which allows me set up a simple online shop. I cannot use any code other than html/css/javascript.

I have put in a simple image-slider in the template. But i want this slider to only be shown on the frontpage. Now its shown on every-page.

Can i use a javascript functions that says something like this: "if url is "www.example.com" then show image-slider else hide it."

Something like this maybe?

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    if(document.URL == "http://example.com/") {
...
...

</script>
```

Thanks on beforehand :)

Comment: Inside the `index` page only, you can put `<script>var isIndexPage=true;</script>` inside `<head>`; than inside the logic of your gallery check for `if(isIndexPage){ /*bla bla here */ }`

Comment: So? ...do you have access to the HTML code of your `index.` page? Can you set some code in there?

Comment: What have you tried with History api? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history

Comment: The History API doesn't seem to be related to what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact circumstances of what you're trying to do it or why you'd need it, but

```
if (location.href == "http://example.com")
```

Should do it. Location.href returns the URL of the page, like "document.URL" in your example.

If you're looking to just get certain parts of the URL, this is a really cool tip I found [here](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561).

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
```

Essentially what this does is creates a link element in your JavaScript that has properties that return different parts of the URL. This would be relevant if there could be multiple URLs for your index page. For instance, if the user is currently at http://example.com/index#something.

```
(location.href == "http://example.com/")
```

Would return false. However, if you did this in your code,

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com/index#something";

(parser.hostname+parser.pathname == "example.com/index")
```

That last line would return true for both http://example.com/index and http://example.com/index#something.
Taking the information you've given about the website, here's my best guess as to what your code should look like.

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = location.href;

if (parser.hostname+parser.pathname != "example.com/index") //If user isn't on the index page
{
    $(".slidewrap").hide(); //Hide the div with the class slidewrap
}
```

Comment: Would be more helpful to explain how to target `index` page only

Comment: Hmm i am really limited in programming and understanding it :D Can you give me a complete code? My slider is in a div called "slidewrap" :) Maybe this can help

Comment: I've made some revisions. Let me know if that's sufficient.

Comment: Hehe i dont think im explaining my self well enough :)

I'm thinking more simple code like:

     <script>
        $(function() {
 if(document.URL !== "http://example.dk") {
        $(".slidewrap").hide(); 
 }
        });
     </script>

(This code is not working. Hope its understandable though)

Answer (score 1):

`window.location` is the right area, it exposes a `hostname` property so you can check just the site name rather than the whole URL, and `pathname` for just the local path within the site. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

So if the home page is http://www.example.com/, then `window.locaton.pathname === '/'`

i.e.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        if (location.pathname == "/") {
            ...
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Im just adding the solution as an answer as i got it to work by mixing j4g and duncans codes:

```
<script>
$(function() {
if(location.pathname !== "/") {
$("#slidewrap").hide(); 
}
});
</script>
```

As i understand it. It says: If location is not index then hide #slidewrap :D And that works perfectly. Thanks.